# Flutter Development (flutter-dev) › Need emergency help.... I can't run flutter app in android device and can't build apk due to gradle issue

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, dart, sdk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AANYt.png)

****When I run these bellow things are shown:**** this issue is occurring with all form Bangladesh

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-6bc433c6b6b5b98dcf4cc11aff31cdee90849f32.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-6bc433c6b6b5b98dcf4cc11aff31cdee90849f32.
         > Could not get resource 
         > Could not get resource 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-6bc433c6b6b5b98dcf4cc11aff31cdee90849f32/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-6bc433c6b6b5b98dcf4cc11aff31cdee90849f32.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-6bc433c6b6b5b98dcf4cc11aff31cdee90849f32/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-6bc433c6b6b5b98dcf4cc11aff31cdee90849f32.pom'.
               > Remote host closed connection during handshake

* Try:
Run with --stack trace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 41s
Exception: Gradle task assembly debug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Answer (score 2):

It clearly says

> Could not GET ...
>
> Remote host closed connection during handshake

Maybe, check if your internet connection is available to the application who is trying to build.

Comment: All of my friends in Bangladesh are facing same problem. I tried more and more by ensuring an internet connection. but fail.

Comment: Probably try a VPN connection.